# Javascript + Prototype: Can I retrieve list option clicked with the onChange event?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I'm having a little difficulty with some JS.

I have a list that I only want a maximum of 10 items selected. The difficulty I'm having is that if a multiple select is made with a mouse drag, the onClick event doesn't fire - so I'm having to use onChange.

BUT, with onChange - I cannot get the last option selected because I think that the DOM doesn't support it in the event. Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<select id="mylist"><option>Test</option>  
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
<option>Test</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
Event.observe('mylist', 'change', checkList);

function checkList(e)
{
    var count = 0;
    var listObj = this;
    // Count selected items
    for (i=0; i < listObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (listObj.options[i].selected) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    // If the count is over, tell me the last selected item
    if (count > 10) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        var tgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
        alert(tgt.nodeName + ' Index:' + tgt.index);
    }
}
```

If I us an `onClick` event then I get 'OPTION - Index 1' for instance. But using `onChange` I get the SELECT node instead.

Is there a way I can reliably get at the clicked option?

Answer (score 0):

What if you just put the logic inside of the for loop?

```
function checkList(e)
{
    var count = 0;
    var listObj = this;
    // Count selected items
    for (i=0; i < listObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (listObj.options[i].selected) {
           // If the count is over, tell me the last selected item
           if (++count > 10) {
               alert('Index:' + i);
               return;
           }
        }
    }

}
```

**or even better:**

Keep your logic and use a selector to get the last selected option:

```
$$('select#mylist option[selected]:last')
```